# Using Former in Laravel with macros

Tags: laravel, macros, laravel-blade

The following works except the value is not populated in the resulting field. When I examine in FireBug I actually see the value set. What gives?

I',m calling Former::populate($someobj) ahead of the macro's use.

```
FORM::macro('BxField', function($fld, $label, $required, $disabled)
{
    $field = Former::text($fld)->label($label);
    if($required) {
        $field->required();
    }
    if($disabled) {
        $field->setAttribute('readonly', true);
    }
    return $field;
});
```

How it is called:

```
{{ FORM::BxField('clname','Last Name',true, false) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. This works. I must have had a error elsewhere that caused this problem.